REST pattern for multiple entities
everyone!
I have two REST endpoints:
/projects
/games
Each project can have multiple games and of course, I can create projects and games by making POST requests to each one of them. No big deal.
But I want to create a "template instantiation" endpoint, where I send a full hyerarchy of the thing like this and the backend take care of creating each entity on their respective tables with correct relationships:
{
    "name": "name of the project",
    "description": "description of the project"
    "games": [{
        "name": "name of the first game",
        "description: "description of the first game"
    },
    {
        "name": "name of the second game",
        "description: "description of the second game"
    }]
}

What would be the correct way on the REST pattern to make this happen?

This seems reasonable. Do you have a more specific question?

I am sorry if I was not clear. My question is, according to REST pattern, this JSON (with full hyerarchy, including sons, grandsons, etc, etc) should go also on the project endpoint or on another specific endpoint? I want to keep /projects and /games and still have the "full json endpoint", like a "template instantiator".

REST means a lot to different people so there's no obvious pattern or right way. That said, having specific POST endpoints with specific media types that result in 1 or more resources being created is a reasonable thing to do. It's the easiest way to model a more complex transation like this. Just make sure it it either fails completely or succeeds completely for robustness.

Can a game ever exist without a project? Can the same game exist on multiple projects?

Games can only exist with a project ID but they must have their own endpoint so the user can grab the game by id as long as it has the correct x-api-key. So, it is kinda shady. If I make games child of project on url, the url would be huge. A game cannot exist on multiple projects but a project can have multiple games.

Taking your comments into consideration: "Games can only exist with a project ID" and "A game cannot exist on multiple projects but a project can have multiple games".
The best solution from the REST API design would be to use method POST for /projects endpoint with the JSON you described. If you do not want to create games, you can always create field games as optional.
P.S. Based on your description I would use the following endpoints:
GET /games/{gameId} - get the game by gameId
POST /projects - create a project
GET /projects/{projectId} - get the project by projectId
GET /projects/{projectId}/games - get games of the project
POST /projects/{projectId}/games - add a game to the project
Further, if necessary, you can add additional endpoints and methods (DELETE - to remove the resource, PUT and PATCH - to full and particular updates on the resource).
